# merging of files and folders in TFS

Tags: tfs

Have a set of files which are modified in a branch say "A.Net". The changes done in these files need to be reflected in another branch say  "B.Net".

One way is to copy the contents of the files from one branch to another branch.
It looks like tedious.

Is there any way to merge from one branch to another branch ?

Answer (score 1):

The thing you're looking to do is called a Baseless Merge in TFS terms.
There's a couple of ways to do it, but you can't do it directly through the VS UI.

Google will give you a number of hits for it, but this one looks like the simplest to follow from a quick scan :

[TFS Baseless merging](https://codemonkeygotsmarts.wordpress.com/2013/02/01/tfs-baseless-merge-between-disconnected-branches/)